# Monitor multiple Jenkins server from 1 Jenkins Server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have multiple installation of Jenkins servers. Is there a way to monitor all the jobs run from one Jenkins server?There is a option for master/slave in Jenkins. But apart from master/slave , is there a possibilty to achieve this?
The Scenario is each Devlopment team has local jenkins. We need to integrate the local jenkins to centralized jenkins. So the local build and deployment can happen in local Jenkins servers, For production deployment they can use Centralized Jenkins server.How to monitor the development Jenkins server.

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps:https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Publisher+Plugin